# Can't copy files on Nexus 5

Tags: rom, nexus-5

nexus 5 won't copy files, keeps giving me error saying "Cannot copy item - The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected". I never had this problem before. Android Debugging is enabled, checked on unknown sources, checked on Media device (MTP).
    i am running custom rom (CARBON hammerhead nightly20140328).

Comment: If you are trying to move files over MTP, that is probably not on topic here unless you made substantial related changes to the ROM yourself and are able to talk aoout the failure in under-the-hood detail from a developer's perspective.  If you are trying to move things via adb push/pull, that actually would be more on topic as that is generally a tool used to support development.  As a matter of purely practical advice, it's worth trying a different cable and host port.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to copy file from depth folder child on your computer?
if yes, move your file to your drive root ( example : "D:\" )
then copy to your nexus 5

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the files you want to copy inside a folder and then copying the folder over to your phone's internal storage.